# (RN) Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): Push Notification

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification

I'm new to React Native. I am sending a link to the app with "push notification". When I tested it, everything works both in the background and when the application is closed. But every time I open the application, I get the following warning. How can I resolve this situation?

WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'remoteMessage.data')

My codes:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Button, Linking, View } from 'react-native'

import styles from './styles/SplashStyles'
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging'
import { DASHBOARD } from '../navigation/routesNames'



const Splash = ({ navigation }) => {

    useEffect(async () => {

        messaging()
            .subscribeToTopic('users')
            .then(() => console.log('Subscribed to topic!'));

        //Notification caused app to open from background state:'
        messaging()
            .onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
                if (remoteMessage.data.url) {
                    Linking.openURL(remoteMessage.data.url)
                }
            });

        //Notification caused app to open from quit state
        messaging()
            .getInitialNotification()
            .then(remoteMessage => {
                if (remoteMessage.data.url) {
                    Linking.openURL(remoteMessage.data.url)
                }
            });
    }, [])


    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button
                title={"Start"}
                onPress={() => {
                    navigation.reset({
                        index: 0,
                        routes: [{ name: DASHBOARD }]
                    })
                }}
            />
        </View>
    )
}

export default Splash
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because at initialization, the value for `remoteMessage` is not yet defined when it is rendered specifically via `remoteMessage.data`, causing the error. If you don't mind introducing a dependency on the lodash package, there's a helper called '[has](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#has)' that checks if path exists. For example:

```
if (_.has(remoteMessage, 'data.url') { ....
```